# can I do insert in update of merge(Implementation SCD type 2)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have source table and a target table I want to do merge such that there should always be insert in the target table. For each record updated there should ne a flag updated to 'Y' and when this in something is changed then record  flag value should be chnaged to  'N'  and a new row of that record is inserted in target such that the information of record that is updated should be reflected. Basically I want to implement SCD type2 . My input data is-

```
student_id   name        city                 state              mobile
1          suraj         bhopal                m.p.             9874561230
2          ravi           pune                  mh              9874563210
3          amit           patna                bihar            9632587410
4          rao           banglore               kr              9236547890
5          neel          chennai                tn              8301456987
```

and when my input chnages-

```
student_id     name    city     state     mobile            
   1          suraj   indore      m.p.  9874561230
```

And my output should be like-

```
surr_key student_id name city state mobile insert_Date end_date   Flag
1             1   suraj bhopal m.p.9874561230 31/06/2015 1/09/2015   N
2             1   suraj indore m.p.9874561230  2/09/2015 31/12/9999  Y
```

Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Comment: Please post the create and insert statements and show your desired output.

Comment: So initially city was indore. now in source it is coming as bhopal? and you want Flag for bhopal will be N?

Comment: initial city is bhopal and current city is indore and yes N for bhopal as it is not active

Comment: then why input data is bhopal?

Comment: that is my source table with initial data and when there is change in source than from city bhopal to indore that is reflected in target

Comment: You are going around in circles. For the very first run, SCD2 will do a sync from source to target.(Bhopal to Bhopal). Then from second run, if any new value is changed in source, it is updated in target (here you want Bhopal -> Indore change) in target. How would the query know that city got changed, if you have kept the same city in input data? Input data doesnt have Indore. Doesnt make any sense. Please properly correct your example.

Comment: man its really simple I don't understand what is the problem as bhopal was the intial place of that student and now he is transferred to indore thats why  indore has flag='Y'

Comment: Ok yeah inodre was added to source I have not updated the information I have added it :) sorry my fault

Comment: @Utsav I have changed my input please can you help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the use of trigger ,you can create before insert trigger on your target table which will update flag column of your source table.
Or you can have after update trigger on source table which will insert record in your target table.

Hope this helps

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

So this should be the outline of your procedure steps. I used different columns in source and target for simplification.

```
  Source (tu_student) - STUDENT_ID, NAME, CITY
  Target (tu_student_tgt)- SKEY, STUDENT_ID, NAME, CITY, INSERT_DATE, END_DATE, IS_ACTIVE
```

The basic idea here is

- Find the new records from source which are missing in target and Insert it. Set start_date as sysdate, end_date as 9999 and IsActive to 1.
- Find the records which are updated (like your Bhopal -> Indore case). So we have to do 2 operations in target for it

  - Update the record in target and set end date as sysdate and IsActive to 0.
  - Insert this record in target which has new values. Set start_date as sysdate, end_date as 9999 and IsActive = 1.

    ```
          -- Create a new oracle sequence (test_utsav_seq in this example)

          ---Step 1 - Find new inserts (records present in source but not in target

          insert into tu_student_tgt
          (
          select 
          test_utsav_seq.nextval as skey,
          s.student_id as student_id,
          s.name as name,
          s.city as city,
          sysdate as insert_date,
          '31-DEC-9999' as end_date,
          1 as Flag
          from tu_student s
          left outer join 
          tu_student_tgt t
          on s.student_id=t.student_id
          where t.student_id is null)

          ----Step 2 - Find skey which needs to be updated due to data chage from source and target. So get the active records from target and compare with source data. If mismatch found, we need to 
              -- a update this recods in target and mark it as Inactive.
              -- b Insert a new record for same student_id with new data and mark it Active.

            -- part 2a - find updates. 
             --these records need update. Save these skey and use it one by one while updating.
          select t.skey
          from tu_student s inner join
          tu_student_tgt t
          on s.student_id=t.student_id
          where t.Flag = 1 and
          (s.name!=t.name or 
          s.city!=t.city)


           --2 b ) FInd the ids which needs to be inserted as they changed in source from target. Now as above records are marked inactive,
            select s.student_id
          from tu_student s inner join
          tu_student_tgt t
          on s.student_id=t.student_id
          where t.Flag = 1 and
          (s.name!=t.name or 
          s.city!=t.city)



           ---2a - Implement update
          -- Now use skey from 2a in a loop and run update statements like below. Replace t.key = with the keys which needs to be updated. 
          update tu_student_tgt t
          set t.student_id = (select s.student_id from tu_student s,tu_student_tgt t  where s.student_id=t.student_id and t.key= -- id from 2a step . )
          ,  t.name=(select s.name from tu_student s,tu_student_tgt t  where s.student_id=t.student_id and t.key= --id from 2a step. )
          , end_date = sysdate
          , is_active = 0
          where t.skey = -- id from 2a step

          ---2b Implement Insert use student_id found in 2a
          --Insert these student id like step 1
          insert into tu_student_tgt
          (
          select 
          test_utsav_seq.nextval as skey,
          s.student_id as student_id,
          s.name as name,
          s.city as city,
          sysdate as insert_date,
          '31-DEC-9999' as end_date,
          1 as Flag
          from tu_student s
          where s.student_id = -- ID from 2b step - Repeat for other ids
    ```

I cannot give you a simple example of SCD-2. If you understand SCD-2, you should understand this implementation.

Comment: In the example you are using same product_id for both records. Isn't product id coming from source? If no then the product_id should be different in your example. Ideally it should be auto-generated in target if it is not coming from source.

Comment: yeah I am sorry the product_id should be changed so when that is the case how will I check that which product id is already in tgt as I cannot use inserts in the sub-query as it will result in an error and in step I have to manually insert?

Comment: So in that case, In step 1, product name should be the identifier. Product ids should be auto generated in target. Else in step 3, use max(product_id) from target while inserting and append it by 1. My answer was based on your example.

Comment: I don't understand can you please give an example

Comment: Before you start implementing SCD-2 you should tell 
   1)  What is the unique identifier in Source? It shouldn't be product name. Should be an integer value.
   2) Product_Id as name suggests should not be changed. You should create a new column in target table which will act as surrogate key
   3) From where are you planning to populate this surrogate key. Ideally it should be an Oracle sequence. 


Once you are sure on above points, give a test input and ouput table. Then we can work on a solution.

Comment: now I am sure the unique identifier in source should be student_id and yes surrogate key is there and it would be oracle sequence also I have added my input and output in question itself...

Comment: I have added as you said

Comment: I understand what you are doing but don't you think its too long... there will be a short way to do this...surely

Comment: How ever you implement it, the steps should be the same in this order. Please accept the answer if it is what you expect.